# Obtener más de dos lineas al reporte: QUERY CASE, GROUP BY y MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas noches,
Estoy consultando esta **query**:

```
   SELECT (CASE area 
                        WHEN 'GER' THEN 'Gerenecia'
                        WHEN 'MRKTNG' THEN 'Marketing'
                        WHEN 'RBMAY' THEN 'Riesg. Banca Mayorista'
                        WHEN 'RBMIN' THEN 'Riesg. Banca Minorista'
                        WHEN 'RMRC' THEN 'Riesg. Mercado'
                        WHEN 'RRHH' THEN 'Recursos Humanos'
                        ELSE 'Ventas'
                        END
                        )AS 'AREA' ,MAX(fecha) AS 'FECHA' FROM movimientos 

   GROUP by area
```

Consiste en que me de la ultima fecha por cada área, pero quiero agregar una columna más que es 'transacción', pero me obliga a ponerlo dentro del **GROUP BY**, quisiera saber si alguien me ayuda a poder agregar esa columna en el reporte.

El reporte se vé así, a ese se le desea agregar la columa pero sin alterar la cantidad de registros.

[image: Reporte]

Al agregar la comulma "transaccion me aparecen más registros de los que quiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor usa [https://www.sqlfiddle.com/](https://www.sqlfiddle.com/) o alguna herramienta para crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿tienes algún error al colocar la columna `transacción` en tu `SELECT`?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave No me aparece ningún error, pero me aparecen más registros de los que quiero que sería un registro por cada área. acabo de agregar la imagen de lo que me muestra para ver si me puedes entender mejor, gracias

Comment: El resultado que obtienes el lógico, el tema es entender que al hacer la agrupación se van a mostrar aquellos registros de los cuales estás seleccionando. Como bien menciona Mauricio, replica tu escenario para que lo podamos ver en línea y a partir de ahí podremos revisar cuales son los resultados que tienes actualmente y cuales son los esperados

Comment: @AntonyAlzaPerez al menos deberías considerar en tu pregunta agregar información de ejemplo, de lo que tienes y lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque no estás siendo 100% claro, entiendo que lo que quieres es agregar la columna `transacciones` y que esta saque su valor del registro que tenga la fecha máxima (`MAX(fecha)`).

En este caso, lo más apropiado es usar la función ventana `row_number()`:

```
select CASE area WHEN 'GER'    THEN 'Gerenecia'
                 WHEN 'MRKTNG' THEN 'Marketing'
                 WHEN 'RBMAY'  THEN 'Riesg. Banca Mayorista'
                 WHEN 'RBMIN'  THEN 'Riesg. Banca Minorista'
                 WHEN 'RMRC'   THEN 'Riesg. Mercado'
                 WHEN 'RRHH'   THEN 'Recursos Humanos'
                 ELSE 'Ventas'
       END AS AREA,
       fecha,
       transacciones
  from (select area,
               fecha,
               transacciones,
               rn = row_number() over (
                        partition by area
                            order by fecha desc)
          from Hoja$) t
 where rn = 1
```